Two foreign keys in one model
I am making my first Django app and I am having trouble exporting some values.
I have a model let's call it Machines with some attributes (buyer, name, model, serial number etc).
My other model is a visit category model that has 2 reasons for the visit (service, inspection)
Finally I have my last model that has visitDetails (date of visit, notes, reason of visit (which is visit category model foreign key, and machine details (which is Machines model foreign key).
How can I get for each visitDetails the reason of visit?
I managed to get all machineDetails for each Machine with:
machine = Machines.objects.get(id=id)
visit_details = machine.details.all() - details is relate_name for machine_details which is an object inside visitDetails model with foreign key Machines.
But I cannot figure out how to also get visit category for each visit.
My code:
def export_to_excel(request, id):

response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/ms-excel')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="export.xlsx"'

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws.title = "Products"

# Add headers
headers = ["FOO", "BAR", "FOO", "BAR"]
ws.append(headers)

# Add data from the model
machine_details = Machines.objects.get(id = id)


details = machine_details.visit.all()


for detail in details:
    ws.append([detail.visitDate,detail.workingHours, detail.loadHours, detail.cNotes])

# Save the workbook to the HttpResponse
wb.title = 'title'
wb.save(response)
return response

MODELS
class Machines(models.Model):

cOwner = models.CharField(max_length=32)
cModel = models.CharField(max_length=32)
cSerial = models.CharField(max_length=32)
cBuyDate = models.DateField()
cTechnician = models.ForeignKey(User, 
on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True, 
related_name="technician")

def __str__(self) -> str:
    return self.cOwner

class visitCategory(models.Model):

visitReason = models.CharField(max_length=64)

def __str__(self) -> str:
    return self.visitReason

class cVisit(models.Model):

itemDetails = models.ForeignKey(Machines, 
on_delete=models.Case, 
blank='True', null='True', related_name="visit")

visitReason = models.ForeignKey(visitCategory, 
on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank="True", 
null="True",related_name="vReason")

visitDate = models.DateField()

workingHours = models.IntegerField(default=0)

loadHours = models.IntegerField(default=0)

cNotes = models.TextField(default="")

def dateRender(self):
    return self.visitDate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")


Can you share the (relevant parts) of the models. It probably makes things easier.

I edited the post with the models and my current code
